# xdotool only works with X11 windows on OSX

Tags: macos, xdotools

I've installed [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) via MacPorts. It works only with X11 windows. Is there a way to use it for native OSX applications as well?

Answer (score 1):

[cliclick](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/) may be a reasonable replacement:

> “Cliclick” is short for “Command-Line Interface Click”. It is a a tiny shell/Terminal application that will emulate mouse clicks or series of mouse clicks (including doubleclicks and control-clicks) at arbitrary screen coordinates. Moreover, it lets you move the mouse, get the current mouse coordinates, press modifier keys etc.